# How to create a class to be serialized to have this output XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

```
<Root>
    <Apple Clr="RedViolet">1</Apple>
    <Apple Clr="RedOrange">3</Apple>

    <AppleGroup Clr="Red">
        <Apple Clr="LightRed">4</Apple>
        <Apple Clr="DarkRed">12</Apple>   
        <Apple Clr="MediumRed">10</Apple>
    </AppleGroup>
    <AppleGroup Clr="Red">
        <Apple Clr="LightRed">4</Apple>
        <Apple Clr="DarkRed">12</Apple>   
        <Apple Clr="MediumRed">10</Apple>
    </AppleGroup>
</Root>
```

I have serialized a class before but only for simple and straight-forward class serialization only. I don't have any idea in this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 seperate Classes 
First one for the whole XML:

```
[Serializable ()]
[XmlRoot ( "Root" )]
public class XmlRootClass{
    [XmlElement ( "Apple" )]
    public List<Apple> apples{
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement ( "AppleGroup " )]
    public List<AppleGroup> applegroups{
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

second one for the Apple

```
[Serializable ()]
public class Apple{
    [XmlAttribute("Clr")]
    public string color{
        get;set;
    }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text{
        get;set;
    } 
}
```

and the third one for the Apple Group

```
[Serializable ()]
    public class AppleGroup{
    [XmlAttribute("Clr")]
    public string color{
        get;set;
    }

    [XmlElement ( "Apple" )]
    public List<Apple> apples{
        get;
        set;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Visual Studio feature to create a Serializable class from any Xml data. 
Firstly you have to copy the Xml data for which you want to create a class and then select **Menu -> Paste Special -> Paste Xml As Classes**

This is very handy and useful in some cases. I am not sure this will fulfill your demand in current case, but this may help you in future.

[image]